# docker-compose/django TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not NoneType

Tags: python, django, docker, docker-compose

I'm trying to set up my Django and postgres dev environment with docker so I can run it on other machines more easily as well as run everything from 1 terminal window (I'll be adding my react front end once I figure out this Django error).

I feel like I'm close, but getting hung up on this error. Looks like this is the output when it runs `start.sh`. I've been following a lot of different guides on this setup and maybe I've just got things out of whack because of that. Not sure where to go from this error.

I am able to successfully execute the `runserver` command outside of the container so this seems to be isolated to the container.

Error:

```
django_server | Traceback (most recent call last):
django_server |   File "manage.py", line 15, in <module>
django_server |     execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
django_server |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 371, in execute_from_command_line
django_server |     utility.execute()
django_server |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 365, in execute
django_server |     self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
django_server |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 288, in run_from_argv
django_server |     self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
django_server |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 335, in execute
django_server |     output = self.handle(*args, **options)
django_server |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 79, in handle
django_server |     executor = MigrationExecutor(connection, self.migration_progress_callback)
django_server |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 18, in __init__
django_server |     self.loader = MigrationLoader(self.connection)
django_server |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 49, in __init__
django_server |     self.build_graph()
django_server |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 200, in build_graph
django_server |     self.load_disk()
django_server |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 99, in load_disk
django_server |     directory = os.path.dirname(module.__file__)
django_server |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/posixpath.py", line 156, in dirname
django_server |     p = os.fspath(p)
django_server | TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not NoneType
django_server | Performing system checks...
django_server | 
django_server | System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
django_server | Unhandled exception in thread started by <function check_errors.<locals>.wrapper at 0x7f2d34a73b70>
django_server | Traceback (most recent call last):
django_server |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 225, in wrapper
django_server |     fn(*args, **kwargs)
django_server |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 123, in inner_run
django_server |     self.check_migrations()
django_server |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 427, in check_migrations
django_server |     executor = MigrationExecutor(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS])
django_server |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 18, in __init__
django_server |     self.loader = MigrationLoader(self.connection)
django_server |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 49, in __init__
django_server |     self.build_graph()
django_server |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 200, in build_graph
django_server |     self.load_disk()
django_server |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 99, in load_disk
django_server |     directory = os.path.dirname(module.__file__)
django_server |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/posixpath.py", line 156, in dirname
django_server |     p = os.fspath(p)
django_server | TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not NoneType
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.7-alpine

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

RUN apk add --no-cache --virtual .build-deps \
    gcc \
    python3-dev \
    musl-dev \
    postgresql-dev


# create and set work directory
RUN mkdir /code
WORKDIR /code

ADD ./requirements /requirements
# COPY ./requirements /requirements

RUN pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip install -r /requirements/local.txt --ignore-installed

# RUN apk del --no-cache .build-deps

ADD . /code/

COPY ./docker_compose/django/development/start.sh /start.sh
COPY ./docker_compose/django/entrypoint.sh /entrypoint.sh
RUN sed -i 's/\r//' /entrypoint.sh \
    && sed -i 's/\r//' /start.sh \
    && chmod +x /entrypoint.sh \
    && chmod +x /start.sh

ENTRYPOINT ["/entrypoint.sh"]
```

docker-compose-dev.yml:

```
version: '3'

volumes:
  local_postgres_data_dev: {}
  local_postgres_backup_dev: {}

services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres:10.5
    env_file: .env
  django:
    container_name: django_server
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./docker_compose/django/development/Dockerfile
    depends_on:
      - postgres
      # - node
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    env_file: .env
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    command: /start.sh
```

entrypoint.sh:

```
#!/bin/sh
set -e
cmd="$@"

# the official postgres image uses 'postgres' as default user if not set explictly.
if [ -z "$POSTGRES_USER" ]; then
    export POSTGRES_USER=postgres
fi

# If not DB is set, then use USER by default
if [ -z "$POSTGRES_DB" ]; then
    export POSTGRES_DB=$POSTGRES_USER
fi

# Need to update the DATABASE_URL if using DOCKER
export DATABASE_URL=postgres://$POSTGRES_USER:$POSTGRES_PASSWORD@postgres:5432/$POSTGRES_DB



function postgres_ready(){
python << END
import sys
import psycopg2
try:
    conn = psycopg2.connect(dbname="$POSTGRES_DB", user="$POSTGRES_USER", password="$POSTGRES_PASSWORD", host="postgres")
except psycopg2.OperationalError:
    sys.exit(-1)
sys.exit(0)
END
}

until postgres_ready; do
  >&2 echo "Postgres is unavailable - sleeping"
  sleep 10
done
>&2 echo "Postgres is up - continuing..."
exec $cmd
```

start.sh:

```
#!/bin/sh
python manage.py migrate
python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

**Edit - adding structure & settings**

Project Structure:

```
.
├── api
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __pycache__
│   ├── admin.py
│   ├── apps.py
│   ├── migrations
│   ├── models.py
│   ├── serializers.py
│   ├── tests.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── views.py
├── financeApp
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── __pycache__
├── build
│   └── webpack-stats.json
├── config
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __pycache__
│   ├── settings
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── wsgi.py
├── database20181022.json
├── datadump20190121.json
├── db.sqlite3
├── docker-compose-dev.yml
├── docker-compose.yml
├── docker_compose
│   ├── django
│   ├── nginx
│   ├── node
│   └── postgres
├── frontend
│   ├── README.md
│   ├── build
│   ├── config-overrides.js
│   ├── node_modules
│   ├── package-lock.json
│   ├── package.json
│   ├── package0.json
│   ├── public
│   └── src
├── manage.py
├── requirements
│   ├── base.txt
│   ├── local.txt
│   └── production.txt
└── templates
    └── main.html
```

Base.py:

```
"""
Django settings for Finance App project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 2.0.4.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/settings/
"""

import os
import dj_database_url

from decouple import config

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(
    os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))))

# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = config('SECRET_KEY')

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = config('DEBUG', cast=bool)

# ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'rest_framework',
    'api',
    'djmoney',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',

]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'config.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "templates"), ],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'config.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/settings/#databases
DATABASES = {
    'default': dj_database_url.parse(config('DATABASE_URL')),
}
DATABASES['default']['ATOMIC_REQUESTS'] = True

# Added this to support deployment on Heroku
# https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django-app-configuration
db_from_env = dj_database_url.config(conn_max_age=500)
DATABASES['default'].update(db_from_env)

# DATABASES = {
#     'default': {
#         'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
#         'NAME': 'finance_app',
#         'USER': 'finance_app_admin',
#         'PASSWORD': '',
#         # 'HOST': 'localhost',
#         'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
#         'PORT': '5432',
#     }
# }


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    # os.path.join(os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'frontend'), 'build', 'static')
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "frontend", "build", "static"),
]

# STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "frontend", "build", "static")

REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PAGINATION_CLASS': 'rest_framework.pagination.LimitOffsetPagination',
    'PAGE_SIZE': 100
}
```

local.py:

```
import socket
import os

from .base import *


# Webpack Loader by Owais Lane
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# https://github.com/owais/django-webpack-loader

WEBPACK_LOADER = {
    "DEFAULT": {
        "CACHE": not DEBUG,
        "BUNDLE_DIR_NAME": "frontend/build/static/",  # must end with slash
        "STATS_FILE": os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "frontend", "build", "webpack-stats.json"),
    }
}

# Django Debug Toolbar
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# https://github.com/jazzband/django-debug-toolbar

MIDDLEWARE += (
    # 'debug_toolbar.middleware.DebugToolbarMiddleware',
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
)

CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = False
CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST = (
    'localhost:3000',
    '127.0.0.1:3000',
)


INSTALLED_APPS += (
    # 'debug_toolbar',
    'corsheaders',
    'webpack_loader',
)

INTERNAL_IPS = ['127.0.0.1', '10.0.2.2', ]
```

Comment: It looks like your django container starts fine, so the issue is probably with your django code. Can you share your django project structure and its settings?

Comment: I've added the project structure and settings files. I'm able to run the Django server in the project directly without issue so it seems odd that there would be an issue inside the container if its started up correctly.

Comment: Can you run your migrations directly too? Looks like your migrations are missing.

Comment: Locally I'm able to run migrations. The container is failing at this step (which is the first thing ran in `start.sh`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your environment variables are defined properly.
For example, try printing BASE_DIR and see what you have there.
It looks like you're missing (some of) them.

The error you're getting might stem from BASE_DIR being assigned None.

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))))
```